# onTabSelected FragmentTransaction show not showing

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

So when I first start up my activity the code will populate each tab, and the `actionBar.addTab(tab,true)` will call on `TabSelected` which will then add each fragment. When I physically click on a tab it should then just call `fragmentTransaction.Show()` and show the fragment.  I just get blank.   Any idea?

Here is the `onCreate` code:

```
// missing some @override stuff etc.

public void onCreate {
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
        View tabView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_title, null);

        TextView titleTV = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.action_custom_title);
        titleTV.setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i));
        titleTV.setSingleLine();
        titleTV.setTextSize(13);
        Tab t = actionBar.newTab()
            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
            .setTabListener(this);
        t.setCustomView(tabView);
        actionBar.addTab(t, true);
    }
}
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    Bundle b = new Bundle();

    switch (tab.getPosition()){
    case 0:
        b.putString("show", getString(R.string.title_section1));
        if (mShowFragment1 == null) {
            mShowFragment1 = EpisodeTileFragment.instantiate(this, EpisodeTileFragment.class.getName());
            mShowFragment1.setArguments(b);
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mShowFragment1);
            addFragmentToActiveList(mShowFragment1);
        } else {
            ft.show(mShowFragment1);
        }           
        ft.show(mShowFragment1);
        break;
    case 1:
        b.putString("show", getString(R.string.title_section4));
        if(mShowFragment3 == null) {
            mShowFragment3 = EpisodeTileFragment.newInstance(getString(R.string.title_section4));
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mShowFragment3);
        } 
        mShowFragment3.getArguments().putAll(b);
        ft.show(mShowFragment3);
        break;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position == 0 || position == 1) {
            return EpisodeTileFragment.newInstance(getString(R.string.title_section1));
        } else  {
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2; 
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: case 0 case 3. You've left 1 and 2. Is that on purpose or what?

Comment: the main problem is that ft.show(fragment) simply doesn't show the fragment. I see the code being hit but it doesn't show.  I don't want to do replace, as I have 2 different fragments with different data on each fragment.  You cannot call ft.commit() on this method because android will be calling commit() for you.

Comment: can you post the `SectionsPagerAdapter` code?

Comment: getItem never gets called but if i set addTab(tab,false);  EVERYTHING runs fine.. except that now when someone taps a tab, i have to load the data for it. I am trying to have every tabs data load in one shot. so addTab(tab,true) makes onTabSelected be called per tab, which should load the data.  I can see that it does in my log statements, but they just arent' visible when I tap each tab physically.

Answer (score -1):

you're calling the wrong method. FragmentTransaction.show works only for a fragment that has been already attached and that is just hidden.

What you're looking for is [fragmentTransaction.commit()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit())

At the same time you might want to [replace()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)) the current shown fragment instead of adding a new one to the existing container.

So, just to summarize:

```
ft.replace(id, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: appreciate the effort but if you add that code it will error.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961160/in-actionbar-sherlock-add-tab-throw-commit-already-called

Comment: I didn't know about the error and probably is not related just to Sherlock. Thinking a little bit more it definitely makes sense. What happens if you try a different approach? Don't call show and just call replace? In theory it should be shown and it should replace every time the fragment with the new one. If it works you can try with your approach but slightly modified: if the fragment by a tag is not added, add it and it will be displayed. If it's there you have to hide the old one and show the new one.

Comment: yup, I've been trying any and all things I can think of.  replace has the same behaviour.  I don't know of any app actually that has multiple tabs, and can "preload" data across every tab onCreate.  it seems that each tab needs to be loaded when a user clicks a tab.  If what I am trying to accomplish is not possible then .. well that sucks.

Comment: Ahah you didn't say about preloading all the tabs. If you think at the end your listener gets just invoked by the tab click but nothing prevents you to add them from outside before hidden. The problem with this approach is that loading content that you don't actually see and that is going to be replaced looks a little bit a waste of resources (obviously it's a matter of the type of app).

Comment: Right, I dont understand why preloading makes them unshowable.  If i don't preload them, and ontabSelected gets called whenever i tap a tab,it will load the data and everything is good.  I can see that the fragmentTransaction is adding the fragments to android.R.content so I don't have to add them again later, i just show/hide fragments as users click around.  onTabUnselected, I hide the fragment, and show the next fragment.   no idea why tapping a tab is any different than addTab(tab,true);  they call the same code.